# Emacs Lisp function with optional argument call other function

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have function like this:

```
(defun swap-region-ring ()
  "replace selected text with the one from kill ring"
  (interactive)
  (backward-delete-char (- (point) (mark)))
  (yank))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c y") 'swap-region-ring)
```

How can I rewrite that function to call yank with argument and have also optional argument so it act the same as yank? So I can call <kbd>C-u 2 C-c y</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yank` happens to accept a "raw prefix argument" as its argument, so you can pick it up and forward it:

```
(defun swap-region-ring (&optional arg)
  "replace selected text with the one from kill ring"
  (interactive "*P")
  (backward-delete-char (- (point) (mark)))
  (yank arg))
```

Type `C-h f interactive` for more information about the interactive spec.